# node.js multiple local servers

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have two sites with almost the same settings for the local environment. I have the one on port 8000, the other on 8008 with debug on 5081 and 5082 accordingly. I want to run them simultaneously so that one of them can make requests to the other. Running grunt is yielding an error "port 35729 is already in use". Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: We'd need to see your Grunt config to really help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a different `livereload` port for at least one of the instances.  See here: https://github.com/toddmotto/fireshell/issues/39